# How do I create a Robots.txt editor in Sitefinity mvc?

Tags: sitefinity

I want to create an editor for the Robots.txt file in Sitefinity. I want to give the user ability to edit this. How do I do this? I am using the latest version of Sitefinity and MVC. Any examples or related articles, etc. will be useful.

Comment: Why do you need the ability for the users to edit the robots.txt file? Can you please edit the question and walk us through your scenario as once you set it up correctly, there should be no need to edit this on the fly and Sitefinity handles a lot of scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has access to Administration > File Manager, then he can go there, download the file, edit it and upload it again. That's the easiest option and does not require custom code.

If that's not an option, then you can create an MVC widget which reads the file and displays it in a textarea for instance. 
User can then make changes and submit them to the controller which will save them to the file.
Then you can place this widget on a custom backend page.